# Merge 2 dictionaries with higher value for each key

Tags: python

I have

```
dict1 = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
dict2 = {b: 3, c: 2}
```

How do I merge dict1 and dict2 so that the result dict3 will have {a: 1, b: 3, c: 3}
I know we can merge like this dict3 = {**a, **b}, but is there a condition anywhere I have to write to make it work for my problem?

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```py
dict1 = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
dict2 = {"b": 3, "c": 2}

result = {}
for k in dict1.keys() | dict2.keys():
    result[k] = max(dict1.get(k, float('-inf')), dict2.get(k,float('-inf')))

print(result)
```

I am using a get with default: `dict1.get(k, DEFAULT)` and joining the two keysets with the bitwise OR operator `|`.

Note that the default of `float('-inf')` means the result for

````py
dict1 = {"a": -1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
dict2 = {"b": -5, "c": 2}```
````

becomes `{'a': -1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}`.

While for the default of `0` you would get
`{'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'a': 0}`

Both ways could be considered equally valid responses.

Comment: You might be able to speed it up a bit by moving `float('-inf')` out of the loop. (replying to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61111041/merge-2-dictionaries-with-higher-value-for-each-key/61111114#comment108113682_61111114))

Comment: My test was unfair. I tested already with default 0, I just realized. So if time was really that of an issue here, your solution would win. However, from the point of readability, I prefer my "for-max" solution over the faster "for-for-if-larger" solution a tiny bit.

Answer (score 3):

You can merge the dict items into one sequence of tuples, sort them, and then use the `dict` constructor to create a new dict from the sorted sequence so that items of the same keys but with higher values will override those with lower values:

```
dict(sorted((*dict1.items(), *dict2.items())))
```

Comment: I really love this solution and I honestly did not see it. It is interestingly a little bit slower than the 2 other solutions. But I fail to see why. I measure 12ms for this one, 3.8 for mine (for-max-solution) and 2.6 for the for-for-if-larger-solution.

Comment: @LydiavanDyke Glad you like it. Not sure how you measure it, but in my testing it is the quickest of the 3 answers for the given input. See demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/ElectronicElasticExams

Comment: I used larger numbers. But on repl.it `n` larger than 100 does not terminate:) https://repl.it/repls/StaleFluffyNotifications

Comment: I see. Indeed the problem with sorting is that it costs *O(n log n)* in average time complexity whereas the other solutions that keep track of the maximum value for each key in a loop cost *O(n)*. So for really large dicts one should stick to the linear solutions. By the way your demo code will finish, but will require a long time. Try lowering the `number` argument for `timeit` since you're using a much larger `n`: https://repl.it/@blhsing/StaleFluffyNotifications

Comment: Ah, I am not used to fiddle with the numbers of timeit. I usually just enter "timeit" in my ipython console. Anyway, it was a pleasure coding with you and @wjandrea. As far as I see it, we got a fast solution, a pythonic solution and a readable solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You could simply loop through them and compare the values, and use [`dict.setdefault(key, 0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to get around unset values.

```
dict1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
dict2 = {'b': 3, 'c': 2}

dict3 = {}
for d in dict1, dict2:
    for k, v in d.items():
        if v > dict3.setdefault(k, 0):
            dict3[k] = v
print(dict3)  # -> {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 3}
```

[`defaultdict(int)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) would also work but I wanted to avoid the import.

Comment: Maybe `float('-inf')` would be a better default, idk

Comment: That is a very good point! You just spotted out a bug. At least for my code.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I didn't know about the dict.setdefault thing

Comment: Hm. Or did you... I am not sure. I think, it could go either way.

Comment: @Lydia That's why I said "idk" ;) Actually though I'm thinking it's better to check for membership first then compare instead of using a default, at least in my code.

Comment: I added that detail to my answer. In production code the docstring would explain the implemented behavior. I totally overlooked it, so anybody who copies the code in the future might as well :)

Comment: Your solution is a bit faster than mine. At least for my sample set (1000 entries with key length 3): you 13.7 µs ± 165 ns per loop . My solution: 18.5 µs ± 218 ns per loop